# How do I build 32-bit binaries with Red Hat Developer Toolset?

Tags: centos, g++, centos7, 32-bit, devtoolset

I can't find any documentation whatsoever on how to target 32-bit with Red Hat Developer Toolset (version 9.0 in this case running on CentOS 7). The release notes mention:

> Generation and manipulation of 32-bit binaries is also supported

It also ships the needed 32-bit libraries in:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/
```

However, building fails. Example trying to build a minimal `int main() {}` program:

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-9 'g++ -m32 tst.cpp'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/libstdc++_nonshared.a when searching for -lstdc++_nonshared
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: cannot find -lstdc++_nonshared
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The library it fails to find actually exists though:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libstdc++_nonshared.a
```

No amount of `-L` flags fixes it (and it would be the wrong solution anyway; the linker should not even be attempting to load 64-bit libraries in `-m32` mode.)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't notice that `/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libstdc++_nonshared.a` is quite likely a dangling symlink:

```
$ file /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libstdc++_nonshared.a
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libstdc++_nonshared.a: broken symbolic link to `../../../i686-redhat-linux/9/libstdc++_nonshared.a'
$
```

The destination file `/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/9/libstdc++_nonshared.a` is however unfortunately not provided by any CentOS package (but it should be in `devtoolset-9-libstdc++-devel.i686`). Thus it's likely a CentOS-specific packaging mistake as [RHEA-2019:4134](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2019:4134) provides the questioned package `devtoolset-9-libstdc++-devel-9.1.1-2.6.el7.i686.rpm` for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 including the desired file (explicitly verified by `yum install /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/9/libstdc++_nonshared.a` on RHEL 7).

Comment: Dang it. You're right. Back to Ubuntu 16.04 then for building my release binaries.

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable for your specific usecase, but there is a [no-cost Red Hat Developer Subscription](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/getting-red-hat-developer-subscription-what-rhel-users-need-know/).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use lock-down systems like this. They might go down and become inaccessible when I need them due to account issues, DRM acting up, or whatever. I need something that I can rely on to work.